popoverTip background color
I am trying to change the background color of a SwiftUI popover tip to always be white. Currently, when we switch between light and dark mode, the background of the popoverTip changes color. I want it to remain white all the time.
Please note that I am using a popoverTip using TipKit, and my code is in SwiftUI and not UIKit. For UIKit, there are ways to get around this issue such as:
let popoverController = TipUIPopoverViewController(sampleTip, sourceItem: sampleButton)
popoverController.view.tintColor = UIColor.orange

however, I cannot find an approach for my popoverTip to have a constant white background color. Any tips or ideas are highly appreciated.
Approaches tried:
I tried creating a custom tip style, "MyTipStyle: TipViewStyle" but this only changes the components within the tooltip, and not the background color of the tip itself.
Text("To")
   .popoverTip(tip3, arrowEdge: .leading, action: {_ in})
   .tipViewStyle(MyTipStyle())

I added:
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).tintColor = .white
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).backgroundColor = .white
UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

all have been unsuccessful in changing the background of the tooltip itself, and they change the background of the components within it instead.
This is the complete example code to try to play around with:
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct InlineTip3: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("Save as a Favorite")
    }
    var message: Text? {
        Text("Your favorite backyards always appear at the top of the list.")
    }
    var image: Image? {
        Image(systemName: "star")
    }
}

struct MyTipStyle: TipViewStyle {
    init() {
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).tintColor = .white
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).backgroundColor = .white
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [TipUIPopoverViewController.self]).overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = configuration.image {
                image
                    .font(.title2)
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            if let title = configuration.title {
                title
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.headline)
                    .textCase(.uppercase)
            }
            if let message = configuration.message {
                message
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 100)
        .preferredColorScheme(.light)
        .overlay(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            // Close Button
            Image(systemName: "multiply")
                .font(.title2)
                .alignmentGuide(.top) { $0[.top] - 5 }
                .alignmentGuide(.trailing) { $0[.trailing] + 5 }
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Invalidate Reason
                    configuration.tip.invalidate(reason: .tipClosed)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct InlineView: View {
    // Create an instance of your tip content.
    var tip3 = InlineTip3()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("A TipView embeds itself directly in the view. Make this style of tip your first choice as it doesn't obscure or hide any underlying UI elements.")
            
            Text("To")
                .popoverTip(tip3, arrowEdge: .leading, action: {_ in})
                .tipViewStyle(MyTipStyle())
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("TipView")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        InlineView()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Could you share your complete swiftui code?

@neyogiry sure thing!

Maybe you could use a TipView with a tipBackground.
Text("To")
    .popover(isPresented: .constant(true), content: {
         TipView(tip: tip3)
            .tipBackground(.white)
     })


this creates undefined popover presentation, sometimes it shows up as a sheet, which is not what I want here.

@amin you can force a popover presentation at all times by adding the following modifier to your TipView(): .presentationCompactAdaptation(.popover)
